# Google Cloud SQL start gives error that request that you start the instance (paradox)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an SQL instance on the Google Cloud that wont start. I haven't used it in a while but now I am attempting to develop the SQL database. I cannot do anything with the instance until it is running, but... pressing start on the instance causes an error that tells me to start the instance. Insane. I did not update anything! I just pressed start. What is the issue here? Is this a bug on Googles end? There's also absolutely no ability for me to delete or reset the instance unless it is running.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try below steps to troubleshoot the issue from your end

1. Since the instance is not running, try  starting the instance in Cloud Shell with the following command

`gcloud sql instances start [INSTANCE_NAME]`

2. If the instance still doesn't start, you can try restarting the instance   by running the following command

`gcloud sql instances restart [INSTANCE_NAME]`

3. Later on, Check the status of the instance by running the following command in Cloud Shell:

`gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]`

Replace [INSTANCE_NAME] with the name of your instance. Look for the state field in the output to see if the instance is running or not.

If the above steps didn’t work  I would recommend you to create a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/) or raise a  [Support Case with Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)